# Use of monitor with two computers

Tags: display

My monitor has multiple inputs which can be quickly selected using a button on the front panel. The DP port is connected to my Ubuntu machine and the HDMI port to my Windows machine.
This worked fine for the past 2 or 3 years and I could switch between the displays. Now when I switch displays away from the DP to the HDMI and back again there is no signal. The only way I have found to recover the display is to restart the Ubuntu machine.
If I turn the monitor off and back on again, the signal also disappears. xrandr config is unchanged since 2017.
Any suggestions on the cause of the problem or where to look?
OS is 20.04.2 LTS, graphics is Radeon RX550.